# Make directory based on filenames before fourth underscore

Tags: bash, automator

I have these test files:

```
ABCD1234__12_Ab2_Hh_3P.mp4
ABCD1234__12_Ab2_Lw_3P.wmv
ABCD1234__12_Ab2_SSV.mov
EFGH56789__13_Mn1_SSV.avi
EFGH56789__13_Mn1_Ve1_3P.mp4
EFGH56789__13_Mn1_Ve2_3P.webm
```

I want to create a context service in Automator that makes directories based on the filename prefixes above like so:

```
ABCD1234__12_Ab2
EFGH56789__13_Mn1
```

...and move the files into those two accordingly. The only consistent variables in the names are underscores, so I was thinking I could delineate by those, preferably capturing the name before the fourth one.

I originally started with this very simple script:

```
for file in "$@"
do
mkdir "${file%.*}" && mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
done
```

Which makes a folder for every file and moves each file into its own folder.

I tried adding variables, various if/thens, etc. but to no avail (not a programmer by trade).

I also wrote another script to do it in a slightly different way, but with the same results to mess around with:

```
for folder in "$@"
do
cd "$1"
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${0%.*}"' {} \; \
-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.*}"' {} \;
done
```

I feel like there's something obvious I am missing.

Comment: Why doesn't your loop use `$folder`?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do what you want with bash parameter expansion operators. You can do it with `sed`.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the rule you want to follow for deriving the directory names from the file name?  I.e. will the pattern always be `{ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS}__{TWO_DIGITS}_{MORE_ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARACTER}_{IGNORED_CHARACTERS}`?  Or will the pattern be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is splitting on dot, but you say you want to split on underscore. If the one you want to split on is the last one, the fix is trivial:

```
for file in "$@"
do
    mkdir -p "${file%_*}" && mv "$file" "${file%_*}"
done
```

To get precisely the fourth, try

```
for file in "$@"
do
    tail=${file#*_*_*_*_}
    dir=${file%_"$tail"}
    mkdir -p "$dir" && mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

The addition of the `-p` option is a necessary bug fix if you want to use `&&` here; `mkdir` without this option will fail if the directory already exists.

Perhaps see also [the section about parameter expansions in the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) which explains this syntax and its variations.

Comment: `$tail` might be worth quoting.

Comment: @konsolebox Good catch, thanks

Comment: The second option worked perfectly. I had done something similar earlier on my own through some trial and error and was reading about needing "-p" but yours is elegant and simple!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

for file
do
    if [[ $file =~ ^(([^_]*_){3}[^_]*) ]]
    then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    else
        echo "${file%.*}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this one to work (most likely my fault) but tripleee's did the trick!